# Deadlock when using condition.wait()

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, race-condition, monitor

Code found here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7942a18fe11ea544

I'm experimenting with the condition.wait without a timeout and am finding myself in a deadlock. The gist of what i'm trying to do is sit in a lock until i've determined that i've created a new file. I'd set a flag and notify the thread, which will then (in my real program) trigger a callback function. at the end of the running, i want to shut down all my threads. I set my loop variable to false, then notify one, which i assumed would unblock the thread. Am i mistaken that this would ignore what the predicate evaluated?

Could someone suggest a better thread layout that would correct the deadlock?
Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
std::atomic_bool new_file_created_{false};
std::atomic_bool run_data_logger_{false};
std::condition_variable file_monitor_condition_;
std::mutex file_monitor_mutex_;
std::thread test_thread_;

void file_monitor_thread_func()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    while (run_data_logger_)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(file_monitor_mutex_);
        file_monitor_condition_.wait(lock, [] { return new_file_created_.load(); });
        if (new_file_created_)
        {
            std::cout<< "New File Created" << std::endl;
            new_file_created_ = false;                       
            //do some stuff
        }
        else
        {}                
    }
}

void end_the_thread()
{
    std::cout << "Ending the Thread" << std::endl;
    run_data_logger_ = false;
    file_monitor_condition_.notify_one();
    if (test_thread_.joinable())
        test_thread_.join();

    std::cout << "Thread Ended" << std::endl;
}

void trigger_new_file()
{
   new_file_created_ = true;
   file_monitor_condition_.notify_one(); 
}

void start_the_thread()
{
    run_data_logger_ = true;
    test_thread_ = std::thread(file_monitor_thread_func);

    trigger_new_file();
}

int main()
{
    for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
    {

        start_the_thread();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);            
        end_the_thread();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use a condition w/o a changed state and mutex on that state.

Answer (score 3):

After `new_file_created_` becomes `true` for the first time, `file_monitor_thread_func` resets it to `false` then loops around and waits for it to become `true` again. But no one ever sets it to `true` again.

Comment: That's incorrect. I loop through 10 times. Each time that i loop, i call start_the_thread() which calls trigger_new_file(), which will set the new_file_created_ to true.

Comment: Before you could get to the second `start_the_thread` call, you must first return from the first `end_the_thread` call, which waits for the first thread to exit, which waits for `new_file_created_` to become `true`, which will never happen because the second `start_the_thread` call will never be reached.

Comment: I do realize that i am hung on the join() from calling the end_the_thread. My problem is in understanding why. 

My assumption/understanding was that i could unblock the condition by calling notify_one(), then because i have set my loop variable to false, i will not hit the  condition.wait() again, and will exit the thread and join. 

If the notify_one() does not actually allow the condition.wait to unblock based on the predicate, then do you have a suggestion to correct the design?

Comment: You passed a condition to `wait` - namely `return new_file_created_.load()` - which means the wait will only only exit once that condition becomes true. That's kind of the whole point of that second argument. `notify_one` doesn't say "get out of `wait` now", it merely says "check the condition again, it might have changed". In your case, it has not: `new_file_created_` is still `false`. So `wait` continues to, well, wait.

Comment: That makes sense. It will always check the predicate return value for validity even though i'm telling it to notify_one(). It will not just bypass it b/c i ask it to. So my options are a timeout using wait_for(lock, timeout, predicate), or a more complex predicate like: wait(lock, [] { return new_file_created_.load() || !run_data_logger_; }

Answer (score 0):

A `condition_variable` is used together with a `mutex`, which is *not* a cosmetic feature. You seem to be under the impression that

```
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(file_monitor_mutex_);
```

is enough to satisfy the precondition of the `wait` method; but **a mutex conceptually only makes sense if it's used for mutual exclusion**. You aren't using it as such, the mutex is only ever locked inside `file_monitor_thread_func`, so mutual exclusion on state changing operations is not guaranteed.

A telltale sign that you are using the monitor incorrectly is that you felt the need to use atomic objects, as the mutual exclusion (that is a prerequisite) guarantees that normal objects can be used.

*There is simply no way to combine a condition and atomic objects*. They belong in different designs.

Comment: My intended use is for the condition to block until woken up or asked to unblock so it can properly close out. The atomic variable is a holdover from when i was using a thread with a sleep to monitor the conditions prior to moving to the condition variable. I will continue to do research on the proper implementation based on my requirements. if you have any suggestions on how to re-organize the code listed above, i'd love to hear them.

Comment: Remove the atomics, and protect all access to the (regular) objects with the mutex.